# angular-timelinejs3 will support Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to integrate 'angular-timelinejs3' in my Angular 6 Project, I got package reference from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-timelinejs3?activeTab=readme . But it is in Angularjs . Is there any possibilities to integrate in Angular 6 or else suggest any timeline chart like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to its github [repository](https://github.com/fmaturel/angular-timelinejs3), it only supports AngularJS (1.x).

Therefore, it is not possible for it to support Angular2+ and beyond. You should look for an alternative library that supports your requirements. You can try using D3.js for that purpose. You shouldn't have any issues using that with Angular.